# iOS geocoding data from google parsing json

Tags: ios, json, geocoding

I'm pulling some data from google maps but I can't seem to do anything with it. Here's my code:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection  {

//do something with the data!
NSError *e = nil;
//parse the json data
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

//get the lat and long and put it into an array
locationData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"%@", [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0]);

}
```

if I log jsonArray.count I get 2, which seems right since google will return results and status at the top level. But if I try to get object 0 it crashes. If I try to do something like this it also crashes:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection  {

//do something with the data!
NSError *e = nil;
//parse the json data
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: receivedData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

//get the lat and long and put it into an array
locationData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(NSDictionary* thisLocationDict in jsonArray) { 

    NSString* location = [thisLocationDict objectForKey:@"results"];
    [locationData addObject:location];
}
}
```

I use this code to get data from Twitter with no problems. The error I get in the console is I am trying to get an object of a string:

```
-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x798a270
```

Here's the json google is sending me:

results =     (
                {
            "address_components" =             (
                                {
                    "long_name" = 2900;
                    "short_name" = 2900;
                    types =                     (
                        "street_number"
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Horizon Dr";
                    "short_name" = "Horizon Dr";
                    types =                     (
                        route
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "King of Prussia";
                    "short_name" = "King of Prussia";
                    types =                     (
                        locality,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "Upper Merion";
                    "short_name" = "Upper Merion";
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_3",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Montgomery;
                    "short_name" = Montgomery;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = Pennsylvania;
                    "short_name" = PA;
                    types =                     (
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = "United States";
                    "short_name" = US;
                    types =                     (
                        country,
                        political
                    );
                },
                                {
                    "long_name" = 19406;
                    "short_name" = 19406;
                    types =                     (
                        "postal_code"
                    );
                }
            );
            "formatted_address" = "2900 Horizon Dr, King of Prussia, PA 19406, USA";
            geometry =             {
                location =                 {
                    lat = "40.0896985";
                    lng = "-75.341717";
                };
                "location_type" = ROOFTOP;
                viewport =                 {
                    northeast =                     {
                        lat = "40.09104748029149";
                        lng = "-75.34036801970849";
                    };
                    southwest =                     {
                        lat = "40.0883495197085";
                        lng = "-75.34306598029151";
                    };
                };
            };
            types =             (
                "street_address"
            );
        }
    );
    status = OK;
    }

and the url I am passing:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=2900+Horizon+Drive+King+of+Prussia+,+PA&sensor=false
```

any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a real solution for your exception but i would recommend you the CLGeoCoder https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html which is built in into the system. There you have the address, coordinate etc..

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't think Apple provided forward-geolocating. Live and learn. : D

Answer (score 3):

The difference from the data that you get from google is that it comes separate by keys, such as `results, geometry, formatted_address`...

You should do something like this:

```
NSError *error;

NSString *lookUpString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&components=country:AU&sensor=false", self.searchBar.text];

lookUpString = [lookUpString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSData *jsonResponse = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lookUpString]];

NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResponse options:kNilOptions error:&error];

self.locationArray = [[jsonDict valueForKey:@"results"] valueForKey:@"formatted_address"];

int total = self.locationArray.count;
NSLog(@"locationArray count: %d", self.locationArray.count);

for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    NSString *statusString = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"status"];
    NSLog(@"JSON Response Status:%@", statusString);

    NSLog(@"Address: %@", [self.locationArray objectAtIndex:i]);

}
```